# Copy cell to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I’m new in this VBA coding and I'm having a little trouble with Equipment ID so I would very much appreciate your help.

Below my problem:

When I create a new equipment, I want to add the Equipment ID by hand since the ID has a letter that depends on the location. For instance, F002. This Equipment ID and all its information will be automatically saved on the first available row on Equipment Inventory (sheet 2). But every time I type, for example, D100, it gives me back blanked on the Equip Manager and “0” on the Equipment Inventory.

This is the code:

```
Sub Equip_SaveNew()
    Dim EquipRow As Long
    Dim EquipCol As Long

    With Sheet1
        If .Range("E5").Value = Empty Then
            MsgBox "Por favor introduza o Nome do Artigo"
            .Range("E5").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If

        EquipRow = Sheet2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1   'First Avail Row. 
        Sheet2.Range("A" & EquipRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet2.Range("EquipID"))

        For EquipCol = 2 To 11
            Sheet2.Cells(EquipRow, EquipCol).Value = .Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, EquipCol).Value).Value
        Next EquipCol

        .Range("E2").Value = .Range("E5").Value 'Add Equipment Name
        .Shapes("NewEquipGrp").Visible = msoFalse
        .Shapes("ExistEquipGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
        .Range("B1").Value = False 'Set Equipment Load To False
        .Range("B4").Value = False 'Set New Equipment To False
    End With

    'Sort Equipment List
     With Sheet2 
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("B2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Range("A4:K" & EquipRow)
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your EquipID range used in this line Sheet2.Range("A" & EquipRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet2.Range("EquipID"))

Comment: I copy that line from other project. On that project, they wrote that line so when an ID was created, it would automatically followed by the last existing ID. They had a sheet with all the ID and they started with 1 and went to 100. So, with that line, the ID created would be automatically 101. Original line is: Sheet2.Range("A" & EmpRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet2.Range("EmployeeID")) + 1. My ID range is F300, F301, G200 and so on. The first letter depends on the location of the equipment. But I want to create an ID and put it manually so that line is useless.

Comment: "EquipID" is meant to be referring to a named range of cells and if this range of cells has not been defined your ID will return as 0. this could be your problem - however its very hard to tell what you're trying to do, because your phrasing is so specific. i would advise that you rephrase your question to make it more generic, or provide a test set of data to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I'm very new in this VBA coding so I'm not sure how to explain in other way. But I decided that my Equipment ID will have only numbers and no letters. It is easier this way. Many thanks again for your time